# Changing a line in a file on UNIX

Tags: unix

I have created a file named "asd.txt" on a UNIX based system.

I added four lines by using echo command.

Now, I would like to change the first line of this file.

I am not allowed to use any text editors, such as vi.

I have to do this by using only command line. Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, there are always many ways.  How about `sed`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you could do it with sed.

```
sed '1 s/search/replace/' asd.txt
```

If you are feeling up to it and have GNU sed, use the `-i` switch to do it in place.

If you want to replace the entire first line how about doing this?

```
echo "Here is my new first line" && sed '1d' asd.txt
```

For both of these commands you can redirect the output to a new file using the `>` operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
cat <(echo "Replacement") <(tail -n +2 foo.txt)
```